# Deallocate pointer on trie

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, free, trie

I'm trying to deallocate pointer on my trie.
here's my trie struct

```
struct trie
{
    int x;
    trie *next[26];
};

trie *head;
trie *tmp;
```

and here's my deallocate function using dfs

```
void deallocate(trie *cur)
{
    for (int a=0; a<=25; a++)
    {
        if (cur->next[a] != NULL)
        {
            tmp = cur->next[a];
            cur->next[a] = NULL;
            deallocate(tmp);
        }
    }
    free(cur);
}
```

and here is my head init function

```
void init()
{
    head = new trie;
    head->x = 0;
    for (int a=0; a<=25; a++)
    {
        head->next[a] = NULL;
    }
}
```

and after the end of the program i called `deallocate(head);`

I'm really new to pointer stuff, is there anything wrong on my deallocate function ? thanks

changed array size and got accepted :) it seems the problem is not the pointer :) thanks everyone

Comment: @piokuc It's presumably a macro which expands to `for int a = 0; a < 25; ++a)`

Comment: Is it really a C++ question? Seems more like C.

Comment: Either way your deallocate function looks fine. Why do you think it works wrong?

Comment: `FOR` is not a standard thing, if it's a macro, I'd like to see it, maybe it's buggy (I don't understand why people invent such things, btw)

Comment: i'm sorry forget to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `new` to allocate memory and `free` to free it. The only error I can see is that you should either use `new` with `delete`, or `malloc` with `free`.

Comment: i just changed the function a little, but i still think something isn't right yet

Comment: @zeulb, you still have `new` and `free` mixed. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6555/To-new-is-C-To-malloc-is-C-To-mix-them-is-sin).

Comment: @BenRuijl i changed free to delete, but still getting runtime error

Comment: @zeulb, it looks ok now in your code. If your code crashes, you probably go out of bounds somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is incorrect for empty input. `deallocate(NULL)` will crash. Functions (especially general ones that constitute framework) should be self sufficient and should be able to cover every possible input.

Answer (score 0):

- deallocate needs to handle NULL input

  if (cur == NULL) 
  {
      return;
  }

  at start of function
- *head should be declared as NULL at declaration

  trie *head = NULL;